# React Native ListView won't update on sorting or after retrieving new data

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native

I am working on a react native app with a `ListView`, which the user can sort. The app polls for new data every so often as well. The data is an array of objects, parsed from some JSON that the app fetched.
However, the list won't actually update in neither of both occasions.

I have logged the array before cloning the `ListView.DataSource`, and the array actually is what I expect it to be. The `DataSource` however doesn't seem to want to update.

I have already tried deep cloning the array, but to no avail.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

Initialisation of my ListViewDataSource:

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
            rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => (r1.value !== r2.value)
        });
        this.state = {
            dataSource: ds,
            sorting: 'availableCapacity',
            sortingOptions: ['name', 'availableCapacity']
        }
    }
```

Refreshing / Sorting the array and cloning it to the DataSource
(Triggered by a button press or when new data is pulled in)

```
refreshList(sortBy) {
    if (sortBy === undefined)
        sortBy = this.state.sortBy;
    var array = this.props.dataToSortAndDisplay;
    if (sortBy == 'option1')
        array.sort(this.sortByVar1);
    else if (sortBy == 'option2') {
        array.sort(this.sortByVar2);
    }
    this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(array)
    })
}
```

I tried deep cloning my array like this, to no avail:

```
cloneData(data) {
    if (data instanceof Array || data instanceof Object) {
        var newData = [];
        for (var k in data) {
            newData[k] = this.cloneData(data[k]);
        }
        return newData;
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

I also tried to deep clone it by using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))`, since the data is just parsed JSON in the first place. Also to no avail.

Can someone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here?
I'm getting quite frustrated, not being able to do something as simple as update a ListView.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the initialization of the list ire data source?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering! I added some code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem, and I'm quite ashamed, really.
The problem wasn't with the ListView after all. My cells saved the data into the state when they mounted, but didn't update it when getting new props.

I just removed the data from the state and used props instead in my cells. This made it work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the ds variable outside of your constructor:

```
var ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => (r1.value !== r2.value) });
class SampleApp extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data) })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <ListView
        dataSource={ this.state.dataSource }
        renderRow={ (rowData) => <Text>{ rowData }</Text> }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Set up a basic demo [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/nWjGfQ).
https://rnplay.org/apps/nWjGfQ

Comment: It didn't make a difference. But thanks for the answer.

Comment: One other option, try resetting your dataSource in your refreshList function like this: `this.setState({ dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data) })` I've also updated my code and the example.

Comment: That's not doing it either, unfortunately

Comment: Hmm. I'm assuming you know for sure that the data is coming back from the api?

Comment: I am. I log the data the moment it should be replaced in the ListView. It actually is the data I'm expecting.
If you change the way it sorts, it doesn't change the rows. The data behind it however does seem to change, because it brings up the wrong page when clicked.